# C# ASP.NET Logging to file with help of ViewState

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

On my page I have this button that triggers an event and logs to a txt file.

```
void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Stop/start service
        var button = (Button)sender;
        string machine = button.CommandArgument;
        string service;

        /*Do stuff */

        if (buttonClicked)
        {
            writeToLogFile("User " + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name + " pressed the " + button.CommandName + " button on server " + machine + " with the services " + checkedBoxes(machine) + " checked.");
            ViewState["buttonClicked"] = buttonClicked;
        }
    }
```

The button changes the state of my page. This state can also be change from other sources, so therefore I log that too.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            prevStatus = new Dictionary<string, ServiceControllerStatus>();
            currStatus = new Dictionary<string, ServiceControllerStatus>();
            buttonClicked = false;
            ViewState["buttonClicked"] = false;
        }
        else
        {
            prevStatus = (Dictionary<string, ServiceControllerStatus>)ViewState["prevStatus"];
            currStatus = (Dictionary<string, ServiceControllerStatus>)ViewState["currStatus"];
            buttonClicked = (bool)ViewState["buttonClicked"];
            if (!buttonClicked)
            {
                foreach (var item in currStatus)
                {
                    ServiceControllerStatus oldStatus;
                    if (prevStatus.TryGetValue(item.Key, out oldStatus) && !(oldStatus == item.Value))
                    {
                        string[] split = item.Key.Split('_');
                        writeToLogFile("The service " + split[0] + " on server " + split[1] + " was changed to " + item.Value + " from another source.");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ViewState["buttonClicked"] = false;
            }
```

But this log also logs when I click the button, which i don't want. Therefore I have to keep the state variable `buttonClicked` between postbacks.

The issue at hand here is the last else case where I reset the ViewState Variable. Everything else works fine. But if I don't have this reset, after I click the button the other logger stops logging since `buttonClicked` stays true. But if I have the reset implemented the ViewState gets set to false at the start of the Page_Load and therefore loses all meaning since it then logs twice, one for the button and one for the other logger. I've been pulling my hair trying to figure out why this else case seems to happen before the if statement.

If I debug and step from a button click event as soon as I hit Page_Load the ViewState is set to false. If I comment out the line within the else case it is not set to false while stepping through debugging. What is going on?

Comment: Just clarifying.. what if you have the logging in the `Page_Load` itself? You have the viewstates available...

Comment: @SujeetSinha I'm not really following what you mean. I call `writeToLogFile` in the `Page_Load` and in the button event for the click. You mean that I should only log from the `Page_Load`?

Comment: When the button is clicked, the Page_Load will be fired first and only after that the button-event. So the ViewState you are setting in the button-event is too late. This won't work. Maybe change your logic so that the logging is not done on postback but as a separate call to some log-method that you call when needed.

Comment: @Esko That is what I get for not taking the time to read up on the page lifecycle. But since this is just a side project during my summer internship i didn't feel like putting in the time... maybe I should. If you have an example of your suggestion feel free to put it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a button is clicked or any other postback fires, the Page_Load event is run before the actual event bind to for example the button. Read more from page lifecycle from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

so the problem is that the ViewState-value you are trying to set happens too late and cannot be evaluated in Page_Load.

One solution is simply to put the logging logic in separate method and call when needed.

Example:

```
 public partial class _Default : Page
    {      

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void Log()
        {            
            if (ViewState["prevStatus"] != null && ViewState["currStatus"] != null)
            {
                prevStatus = (Dictionary<string, ServiceControllerStatus>)ViewState["prevStatus"];
                currStatus = (Dictionary<string, ServiceControllerStatus>)ViewState["currStatus"];                

                foreach (var item in currStatus)
                {
                    ServiceControllerStatus oldStatus;
                    if (prevStatus.TryGetValue(item.Key, out oldStatus) && !(oldStatus == item.Value))
                    {
                        string[] split = item.Key.Split('_');
                        writeToLogFile("The service " + split[0] + " on server " + split[1] + " was changed to " + item.Value + " from another source.");
                    }
                }                
            }           
        }

        protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Do stuff

            this.Log();
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Stop/start service
            var button = (Button)sender;
            string machine = button.CommandArgument;
            string service;

            /*Do stuff */
            writeToLogFile("User " + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name + " pressed the " + button.CommandName + " button on server " + machine + " with the services " + checkedBoxes(machine) + " checked.");
        }

    }
```